# Visualizing $T = T^{\mu}_\nu \frac{\delta}{\delta x^{\mu} } \otimes dx^{\nu} $

Tags: differential-geometry

If $ T $ is a $(1,1)$ tensor on a manifold, and

$$T = T^{\mu}_\nu \frac{\delta}{\delta x^{\mu} } \otimes dx^{\nu} $$ .

how do I visualize this, in order to prove something with it? I need to prove 
 $$  F_{*}(T^{\mu}_\nu \frac{\delta}{\delta x^{\mu} } \otimes dx^{\nu} ) = T^{\mu}_\nu \frac{\delta y^{\alpha}}{\delta x^{\mu} }\frac{\delta y^{\nu}}{\delta x^{\beta} }\frac{\delta }{\delta y^{\alpha} }\otimes \delta y^{\beta} $$,

but, even though I have already discussed this problem with other people, I haven't understood the problem, I beleive it is because I can't visualize this, as to get an idea of what to prove, and the starting point of that is how to visualize something like T

Any comment, response would be much appreciated

Comment: What is $F_*$?  $,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: @Trux: 1. Not sure this counts as "visualization", but your $T$ is a field of endomorphisms. How do you feel about change of basis in general? 2. On the right in your second display, the second $\mu$ should probably be $\beta$...?

Comment: @Bernard8 $F_*$ is a push forward, (that is, a function sends a tangent vector from a manifold M to a tangent vector in a manifold N)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang 1. I'm very familiar with linear algebra change of basis. And I know that a result in diff geom says that  diferentiable function between two surfaces N,N is indepedent from the charts. 2. That's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$The tensor
$$
T = T_{\nu}^{\mu}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x^{\mu}} \otimes dx^{\nu}
$$
is the endomorphism field with matrix $T_{\nu}^{\mu}$ with respect to the coordinate frame $(\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{\nu}})$. If $F$ is a local diffeomorphism (so that $F$ pushes forward $1$-forms via $F_{*} dx^{\nu} = (F^{-1})^{*} dx^{\nu}$), the transformation law
$$
F_{*}(T_{\nu}^{\mu} \frac{\dd}{\dd x^{\mu}} \otimes dx^{\nu})
= T_{\nu}^{\mu} \frac{\dd y^{\alpha}}{\dd x^{\mu}} \frac{\dd x^{\nu}}{\dd y^{\beta}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y^{\alpha}} \otimes dy^{\beta}
$$
follows from the chain rule in the form
$$
F_{*} dx^{\nu} = (F^{-1})^{*} dx^{\nu} = \frac{\dd x^{\nu}}{\dd y^{\beta}}\, dy^{\beta},
\qquad
F_{*} \frac{\dd}{\dd x^{\mu}} = \frac{\dd y^{\alpha}}{\dd x^{\mu}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y^{\alpha}}.
$$

Conceptually, this transformation rule may be viewed as analogous to the similarity $A' = PAP^{-1}$ if $A$ and $A'$ are matrices of a single linear transformation with respect to bases $B$ and $B'$, and $P$ is the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$. (Here, $(P^{-1})_{\beta}^{\nu} = \frac{\dd x^{\nu}}{\dd y^{\beta}}$ and $P_{\mu}^{\alpha} = \frac{\dd y^{\alpha}}{\dd x^{\mu}}$.)